# Blender BGE import nameerror

Tags: python-3.x, blender

I have installed Blender 2.73, and have looked at several tutorials, and the Blender API documentation for Python, and they showed me to use bge to move objects, however I have been getting several errors from my Blender when I run the script.

```
NameError: name 'bge' is not defined
```

So I imported the bge file, however it then give me a ImportError

```
ImportError: No module named 'bge'
```

I have looked in my Blender files, and have been unable to find a bge file, if I could have manually imported it or moved the file. I then downloaded the rar file of Blender, to check for a bge however no luck there. So I then looked for a possible answer online, if it was an individual download or if I had missed something but I was unable to find anything that could solve my issue.

I am able to run other python modules like bpy, it seems like it is only bge that is missing in some sense. I am running Windows 7 and I already had Python 3.4 installed before Blender.

The code that I am using is attempting to spin the basic cube.

```
Controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
Owner = Controller.owner
Move = Controller.actuators['Spin']
PressLeft = Controller.sensors['SpinLeft']
PressRight = Controller.sensors['SpinRight']
Speed = Move.dRot[1]

if PressLeft.positive:
  Speed = Speed + 0.5
  Move.dRot = [0.0, Speed, 0.0]
  Controller.activate(Move)
elif PressRight.positive:
  Speed = Speed - 0.5
  Move.dRot = [0.0, Speed, 0.0]
```

And yes, I know that my code doesn't fit the recommended setup.

Comment: Are you running this code with Blender's bundled Python, or your other install? You would need to run it in Blender.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Yes, this is all through the Blender program/console

Comment: You can get help with blender specific scripting at [blender.stackexchange.com](http://blender.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bge` module is for the Blender Game Engine, it is only available while the game engine is running, it cannot be accessed from blender's python console.

To run python code in the game engine you connect a python controller to your sensor and start the game engine.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, I must have missed that step somewhere along the way because I thought that it would be able to run bge without running the game engine.